# \setcounter{section} numbering not working

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

Here is what I am working with:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcounter{mysection}
\let\realsection=\section
\renewcommand\section[1]{\refstepcounter{mysection}%
  \subsection*{\themysection.\space #1}
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{}
abc

\setcounter{section}{7}
\section{}
def

\end{document}
```

However, the sections still display in proper numerical order, e.g. 1, 2, etc. instead of displaying 4 and then 7.

Comment: Out of the blue: shouldn't you set the `mysection` counter instead?

Comment: Yes. According to your definition you have to change `mysection`.

Comment: I find this definition rather strange and it's unclear to me what's the purpose of this all

Comment: Also @ChristianHupfer I need all the features of the document class amsart but just a single thing changed - the position of the section from center to left aligned justification

Comment: there's a better way to change the `\section` definition.  copy the definition out of the `amsart.cls` file, wrap it in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`, and remove the command `\centering` from the last argument.

Comment: @morphic This clearly is an XY question: you should first tell what your aim is, then the attempt you made. Of course you should simply `\refstepcounter{section}`, but following Barbara Beeton's advice is much better.

Comment: The redefinition of `\section` doesn't really do anything useful, other than break the following document by redefining it not to use the `section` counter. Just delete that definition.

Answer (score 3):

Either follow Barbara Beeton's advice or patch the `\centering` command out of the definition (see `amsart.cls`)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\section}{%
  \normalfont\scshape\centering}{%
  \normalfont\scshape}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}%



\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{A section}
abc

\setcounter{section}{7}
\section{Another text}
def

\end{document}
```

[image]